# ¿Por qué las imágenes en las preguntas no se abren sin tener que navegar a otra URL?

Tags: discusión

Para dar un ejemplo concreto (*ocurre en todas*), si van a ver la pregunta.

['mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/530637/16597)

Si hacen clic para ver más de cerca la imagen, automáticamente somos redirigidos a una nueva URL, puntualmente a la URL de la imagen.

Particularmente a mi, este comportamiento, me resulta bastante molesto, ya que obliga a tener que navegar hacia atrás para volver a la pregunta.

Imagino que existe una buena explicación para no usar otro tipo de "herramienta" para visualizar las imágenes, pero realmente creo que es algo que se podría mejorar/cambiar.

Comment: Si no esta contestado en meta general, es una excelente pregunta.. yo no tengo ni idea, pero ese comportamiento debe ser de toda la red....

Comment: Si, es de toda la red. Te soy sincero, no puedo creer que a nadie más le moleste esto. Debo ser bastante odioso xD

Comment: a mi no me molesta... salvo casos muy puntuales aca no deberia haber casi imagenes...

Comment: Por ejemplo, en esa pregunta que mostras, la imagen no aporta absolutamente nada a la pregunta....

Comment: Con el _"casí"_ te pusiste al medio, ni del "no", ni del "si". Si bien es cierto que en algunas preguntas las imágenes no aportan nada, pero en otras si aportan. No vale la pena ponerse a buscar en cuales si y en cuales no. Lo cierto es que hoy si se puede y personalmente que la forma actual para visualizarlas no es la mejor.

Comment: Muuuuy molesto ese comportamiento, ni hablar si estas a medio escribir un comentario.

Comment: Tal cual, o si estás respondiendo y queres ver con más detalle la imágen.

Comment: Yo generalmente para que no me moleste dicha imágenes pulso con el botón derecho del ratón y  selecciono abrir enlace en una pestaña nueva, como resultado obtendras dos pestaña, una con la imagen y otra con la pregunta

Comment: ¿Qué alternativa sugieres? ¿Que se abra en otra pestaña? ¿Que se abra en un modal? ¿Que no sean enlace directamente?

Comment: Algo parecido a que se abra en otra pestaña @fedorqui

Comment: Parece que la respuesta oficial está en [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2276/209901): si quieres abrirlo en una nueva pestaña, usa Ctrl, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui, me parece que la respuesta más votada en [Support showing image in original size in overlay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151793/347643) sería la indicada.

Comment: @fedorqui _"¿Qué alternativa sugieres?[...]"_ me encantaría que para celulares fuera como en Instagram y para el resto un popup como Whatsapp, Telegram, etc.

Comment: @Rubén, gracias por tu comentario, ya actualice la pregunta.

Comment: agregare esto a una de las capacidades que tiene mi extensión de SOes ... de verdad a mi me molesta pero no suelo tener la necesidad de darle click a la imagenes ...

Comment: click con el boton de la ruedita, o CTRL + click abren cualquier cosa en una pestaña nueva.

Comment: Estaría bueno que SO tubiera una especie de ventanita extra (como la de votos de cierre) para ver la imagen.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo, Me sucede bastante cuando quiere responder, y me apoyo en la imagen para cualquier dato, y puff me saca